# Inheriting a case class from a abstract class without code duplication

Tags: scala

After some amount of googling I wrote this code

```
abstract class Foo(val name: String)
case class Bar(override val name: String, age : Int) extends Foo(name)
def sayHello(f : Foo) = println(f.name)
sayHello(Bar("bar", 10))
```

but it bothers me that there is so much of code duplication between Foo and Bar. all fields are duplicated between Foo and Bar and then I have to pass all the fields of Foo when I do extends.

I wonder if there is a concise way of writing the code above.

Comment: " so much of code duplication between Foo and Bar" -- You mean the declaration of one field in `Foo`? I think this is a bit exaggerated.

Comment: I had to redefine every field of Foo in Bar (even though Bar is a child of Foo) and then I had to pass every field to Foo at the time of extends. Now here it may not look much .. but in real life my Foo had 8 Fields and the code looks very ugly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can decrease amount of duplication, if you make `name` a normal field in `Foo` instead of a constructor argument:

```
abstract class Foo {
  val name: String
}

case class Bar(name: String, age: Int) extends Foo
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create class/trait dependencies without member duplication, but it makes instantiation more verbose so I'm not sure it actually achieves much code reduction.

```
trait Foo {val name: String}            // has name
class Bar(val age: Int) {self:Foo => }  // has age

def sayHello(f : Foo) = println(f.name) // unchanged
sayHello(new Bar(10) with Foo{val name = "bob"})
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you could do this with a macro to generate the appropriate code at compile time, but otherwise there is not much you can do.